# RAISINGINGIN rebus

Tags: wordplay, rebus

> THE RAISINGINGIN

Does anyone know what this could mean?  (as a rebus puzzle)

Answer (score 14):

This rebus means

> "Singing in the rain", since the word "singing" is inside the words "the rain".

Comment: Isn't it SINGING in THE RAIIN here though?

Comment: @boboquack True. Transcription error? This seems too plausible to be incorrect to me.

Comment: I'd say so. Just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Or I SINGING in THE RAIN.

Comment: looks like Helen posted this and never returned to puzzling again